# How to access and call a variable in a static method to use in another Class in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a static method which splits a person's name into 3 variables.
FirstName, MiddleName and LastName.
How do I access the firstname or middleName or LastName variables in another class.

Code:

```
public static string SplitFullName(string Full_Name)
    {
        string[] names = Full_Name.Split(' ');
        string FirstName = "";
        string MiddleName = "";
        string LastName = "";
        if (names.Length == 0)
        {
            FirstName = "";
            MiddleName = "";
            LastName = "";
        }
        else if (names.Length == 1)
        {
            FirstName = names[0];
        }
        else if (names.Length == 2)
        {
            FirstName = names[0];
            LastName = names[1];
        }
        else
        {
            FirstName = names[0];
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < names.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            MiddleName += " " + names[i];
            continue;
        }
        LastName = names[names.Length - 1];
        Console.WriteLine("The first name is: " + FirstName + ";   The middle name is: " + MiddleName + ";    The last name is: " + LastName);
        return Full_Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: the concept of first/middle/last names doesn't always translate well into all cultures - and neither does the idea of spaces; there's also issues with non-trivial names, prefixes, suffixes, connecters, etc; YMMV, but *usually* it is better just to ask explicitly for people to populate their name *as they want it*, rather than guessing. Names don't generalize very well.

Comment: To follow up on Marc's comment: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would pass them out directly to the caller when they call the method. You could, for example, do something like:

```cs
public static void ParseFullName(string fullName,
    out firstName, out middleName, out lastName)
{
    // (remove FirstName/MiddleName/LastName declarations)
    firstName = middleName = lastName = "";
    // populate firstName, middleName, lastName etc instead of
    // your current FirstName etc locals
}
// ... and usage
YourType.ParseFullName(someValue, out var first, out var middle, out var last);
// now use first/middle/last
```

or

```cs
public static (string FirstName, string MiddleName, string LastName)
    ParseFullName(string fullName)
{
    // ...
    return (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName);
}
// ... and usage
var (first, middle, last) = YourType.ParseFullName(someValue);
// now use first/middle/last
```

Answer (score 1):

For now, your code is returning what it's reading, i.e. the `Full_Name` itself.

If you can modify the code to return a `Name` object that contains 3 properties, namely `FirstName`, `MiddleName` and `LastName`, that will allow you to access any of those properties from the caller method.

Like this:

```
//Create this type
public class Name{
  public string FirstName{get;set;}
  public string MiddleName{get;set;}
  public string LastName{get;set;}
}

//This is your method    
public static SplitFullName(string Full_Name)
{
   //Split names here
   ...
   
   //Return the Name object like this:
   var name = new Name{
     FirstName = firstName,
     MiddleName = middleName,
     LastName = lastName
   };
}

//This is where you call from - may be the Main().
CallerMethod(){
  var resultName = SplitFullName("Abc K Xyz");
  Console.WriteLine("Middle name is: " + resultName.MiddleName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recomended you encapsulate this into a `User` class like this:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("User {FirstName},{MiddleName},{LastName}")]
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
    }

    public User(string fullName)
    {
        this.SetFullName(fullName);
    }

    public void SetFullName(string fullName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName))
        {
            this.FirstName = this.MiddleName = this.LastName = string.Empty;
            return;
        }

        var index1 = fullName.IndexOf(' ');
        if (index1 < 0)
        {
            // No spaces
            this.FirstName = fullName;
            this.MiddleName = this.LastName = string.Empty;
            return;
        }

        var index2 = fullName.LastIndexOf(' ');
        if (index2 < 0 || index1 == index2)
        {
            // Only one space
            this.FirstName = fullName.Substring(0, index1);
            this.MiddleName = string.Empty;
            this.LastName = fullName.Substring(index1 + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            // At least 2 spaces
            this.FirstName = fullName.Substring(0, index1);
            this.MiddleName = fullName.Substring(index1 + 1, index2 - index1 - 1);
            this.LastName = fullName.Substring(index2 + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, you only need create an `User` and set the fullName. Then, you can access to each part of name with the user's properties.

My code for `SetFullName` maybe appear more complicated than your `Split` option but is more efficient because don't create the splitted array of strings. I only look for first and last space and get 1, 2 or 3 parts for the properties. Is more code, but for the machine is less effort.

You may check in this way:

```
var u1 = new User("");
var u2 = new User("Name");
var u3 = new User("Name Last");
var u4 = new User("Name Middle Last");
var u5 = new User("Name Mi dd le Last");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could pass out an object

```
public class ParseFullNameResult{
     public string firstName = "";
     public string middleName = "";
     public string lastName = "";
}

public static ParseFullNameResult ParseFullName(string fullName){
    ParseFullNameResult result = new ParseFullNameResult();
    // do your thing
    return result;
}
```